# What languages do twitter and facebook use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

I'm using php for the last 6 months and i can pretty much do anything with it. But BIG websites like Facebook and Twitter don't appear to use php. I want to know what languages they use and **why** they chose that language over php.

Is Ruby on Rails a good language to build robust and big websites? I've seen RoR's video on youtube mocking other frameworks and languages. Is it really *awesome*?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be re-titled. Something along the lines of "Viability of Ruby on Rails or alternatives for large-scale, robust, web applications?" No matter what, the floodgates are open.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting your information but Facebook was initially built exclusively in PHP. Facebook is so ingrained with PHP that they [built several virtual machines](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/the-hiphop-virtual-machine/10150415177928920) to get PHP to work at the scale they are using it and even created a superset language called [Hack](http://hacklang.org/). Why they bothered though instead of choosing better tools for job is beyond me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

twitter is built on Ruby on Rails

facebook uses PHP primarily, but also relies on "C++, Java, Python and Erlang" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook#Server_infrastructure

Comment: Why the -1?  He answered the question succinctly.  Except for that third line editorial opinion, but we can ignore that.

Comment: FYI: Twitter recently switched from Ruby on Rails (ROR) to Java as ROR is not much scalable... Twitter's migration to java has impacted ROR reputation a lot.

Comment: Actually, Twitter switched on Scala, not on Java. It is true that Scala runs on JVM and it is compatible with Java, but it is a different language.

Comment: Facebook has a toolchain called HipHop (or HPHP) that compiles PHP code to C++ code, to speed things up. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP

Comment: Twitter runs on stack of technologies, the languages are  Scala and Java runs on JVM.
You can notice the various languages and opensource platforms that are being used in Twitter.  Finagle is one of main framework that twitter depends on.

Comment: As @QuiteNothing says, twitter replaced it's ROR with Java and Scala for scalability and extensibility.

Comment: I do believe that facebook uses [Hack](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.intro.whatis.php) primarily now - but since Hack is interoperable with PHP the line is pretty blurry; if I run a legacy PHP program on HHVM is it suddenly Hack?

Answer (score 34):

- [Twitter on Scala](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/twitter_on_scala.html)

> It began its life as a Ruby on Rails
>   application, and still uses Ruby on
>   Rails to deliver most user-facing web
>   pages. But about a year ago they
>   started replacing some of the back-end
>   Ruby services with applications
>   running on the JVM and written in
>   Scala

- [Facebook Technology stack](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=203367363919)

> Facebook’s technology stack consists
>   of applications written in many
>   languages, including PHP, C, C++,
>   Erlang and others.

Answer (score 7):

At this point Twitter mostly runs on Scala (though with some Ruby on Rails thrown in) ([cite](http://developers.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=09/04/07/1928218)).

Facebook runs mostly PHP, but also uses some C++, Java, Python and Erlang on the back-end ([cite](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack)).

Answer (score 7):

I would say that this depend on how familiar are you with the language. Any language can be use to build **robust and big websites**

Comment: I was trying to build a social networking website using Assembly language, it takes quite a bit of work

Comment: @HaiPhan, dude you are such a hustler ;)

Answer (score 6):

Large website optimization is typically a matter of how you optimize database queries.

In terms of the language itself, you can always run PHP on more computers as they become saturated. Their isn't really anything that prevents PHP from working on large websites, it is more about the type of code that you are comfortable using.

And yes, I think Ruby/Python produces better code, but in the end, any code can be made to look horrible and run slowly.

Answer (score 3):

twitter actually uses scala now

Comment: Only for part of the site. They still use RoR for a lot of it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Twitter currently use many programming language(C++, Java, Scala, Ruby on Rails)on server side  similarly like other web application like facebook use Hack, PHP, C++, Java, Python, Erlang, D Xhp.

[Here is detail and updated Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_languages_used_in_most_popular_websites)